# How to specify a common parent folder to tar files from different sources into

Tags: tar

Here is the current command I'm running:

`tar --directory=/Users/joe/images -czvf images.tgz dir1/image1.jpg dir2/image2.jpg`

As you can see, this is using `/Users/joe/images` as the root directory, and then including images from different directories under that root.

However, I need to be able to include those images under a common parent inside of the tar, such that if I were to then open that tar file, I would see this directory structure:

- common/image1.jpg
- common/image2.jpg

Is there a flag or way to execute this command that allows me to specify that "parent" directory that files should go under?

Comment: If all the images are just one level deep, try `--strip-components=1`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `--directory` suggests you're using either GNU or modern BSD tar.

With GNU `tar`:

```
tar --directory=/Users/joe/images --transform='s|[^/]*|common|' \
  -czvf images.tgz dir1/image1.jpg dir2/image2.jpg
```

With BSD tar:

```
tar --directory=/Users/joe/images -s'|[^/]*|common|' \
  -czvf images.tgz dir1/image1.jpg dir2/image2.jpg
```

The idea being the same: replace the leading path component with `common`.

Note that that substitution also applies to symlink targets in there (which you can disable with the `S` flag to the substitution).